# Using multi-line value in .env file in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have an installer which pumps out some values to a .env file to be used by docker-compose. All of this has worked so far with the exception of an SSH key which cannot be seemingly used.

I have so far tried with both the correctly formatted private key and also replacing new lines with `\n`. However, this breaks the work flow further down the line and does not appear using printenv within the container as a multi line variable which is required.

docker-compose.yml

```
myservice:
  build: .
  environment:
    - SSH_KEY
    - SINGLE_LINE_VALUE
```

.env (ignore the obviously broke sshkey)

```
SINGLE_LINE_VALUE=I Load just fine
SSH_KEY="---------------
ABCDEFGH
--------------------
"
```

by the time the container is running, the environment value for SSH_KEY is simply "---------------

Any ideas very much appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind not using the `.env` file (maybe that environment variable is used only in a single container). You can define environment variables directly inside `docker-compose.yml` and there, you can make full use of YAML formatting options. I.e.:

```
myservice:
  build: .
  environment:
    SSH_KEY: >
      --------- WHATEVER ----------
      randomkeybase64thingforyourse
      rvice
      ------- END WHATEVER --------
```

And as a side note, you don't have to copy `.env` values inside the `environment` section. `.env` variables are used inside the `docker-compose.yml` file, but not in the container's environment. However, you can do:

```
myservice:
  build: .
  env_file:
    # Files in this array have the same format as `.env` files, but they are
    # passed to container's environment instead being used inside this
    # `docker-compose.yml` file
    - variables.env
  environment:
    SSH_KEY: >
      --------- WHATEVER ----------
      randomkeybase64thingforyourse
      rvice
      ------- END WHATEVER --------
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape dollar signs with a second sign, e.g. `$$` instead of `$` (since `docker-compose` dynamically updates these). Also, worth noting here that you can also use `|` syntax to preserve newlines.

Answer (score 4):

According to dotenv's documentation ([link](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#multi-line-values)), which is used to parse the envfiles within Docker Compose, one should use double quotations with new-lines (`\n`) to achieve new lines after parsing.

Example:

```
PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSU72AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgf+zcD+dC95xJH2YIGtZxg6cBEtZYzeMHZIdAtGarkfahRANCAAReRj+7DNK3rfudJGSo2k9mUBhmz2zqE3d4sfpkIGUizc1s8UXYmnhgezq6fceV9o6HG1I6BdVWi5cfbwTB17Qf\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the nicest solution but at least working.

.env

```
KEY="--------------- \n ABCDEFGH \n --------------------"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  test:
    image: ubuntu
    environment:
      - SSH_KEY=$KEY
    command: bash -c "echo \"$${SSH_KEY}\" | perl -pe 's/\\\n/\n/g' "
```

$$ means escape for dollar sign so docker-compose won't evaluate that variable in .yml file but in runtime

perl replace is required as docker-compose will automatically add escaping slashes to new line characters.

Comment: Hoped I could make it agnostic of the image being run. The use case I have for this is loading the environment variable into jenkins using the JCasC plugin which uses environment variables.. However I am thinking thta potentially a solution using tr may work too as it wouldn't require perl. It requires the key to be loaded with new lines replaced with " ". On host system at least echo "<KEY>" | tr " " "\n" formats the key close enough but again its hacky.

Answer (score 2):

I had managed it to work with dbl-quotes:

docker-compose.yaml

```
myservice:
  build: .
  environment:
    - JAVA_OPTIONS
    - SINGLE_LINE_VALUE
```

.env

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="
  -Doption1=value1
  -Doption2=value2
  -Xms=8g
"
```

docker compose config

```
...
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTIONS: |2

          -Doption1=value1
          -Doption2=value2
          -Xms=8g
...
```

Comment: for `docker run --env-file .env` it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when trying to add a certificate to my docker.env file which would not be picked up correctly.

Had it like this in the .env file which **didn't work**:

```
CERTIFICATE=MIIC5DCCAk2gAwIBAgIJAKgUiZPOajC0MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMFYxCzAJBgNV
BAYTAkRLMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpTb21lLVN0YXRlMQ8wDQYDVQQHEwZBYXJodXMxITAf
...
```

**This worked** (note the \n):

```
CERTIFICATE=MIIC5DCCAk2gAwIBAgIJAKgUiZPOajC0MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMFYxCzAJBgNV\nBAYTAkRLMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpTb21lLVN0YXRlMQ8wDQYDVQQHEwZBYXJodXMxITAf...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. Docker wouldn't read in newlines in my .env file. My solution was to replace each newline with a "%" in .env. In my source code I got the environment variable and replaced each "%" with a newline.

It's not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I will offer my own option for `docker run`. The problem of passing multi-line variables in a .env file was discussed here. https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12997 .
The developers suggest solving the problem using sh/bash

How to solve the problem using shell

1. putting multi-line data into a file and import to variable

MY_VAR.env

```
Text
Text
Text
```

`docker run -e MY_VAR="$(cat MY_VAR.env)"`

2. If you need to pass many variables from a file, then you will have to do a compound query

Variables format in file `-e NAME_VARIABLE="Multi-line text" \`

my.env

```
-e MY_VAR="
Text
Text
text
" \
-e MY_VAR2="TEXT" \
-e MY_VAR3="TEXT
TEXT
TEXT"
```

`sh -c "docker run $(cat my.env)"`