# In docker how to pass environment variables with multiple lines from a enironment file

Tags: docker

In the environment file I have multiple variable of which one is a certificate which has multiple lines. How do I represent that in the environment file. Currently it is only picking up only the first line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Multiline Environment Variable with Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299617/set-multiline-environment-variable-with-dockerfile)

Comment: [Using multi-line value in .env file in docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475228/using-multi-line-value-in-env-file-in-docker-compose), if that describes your setup, suggests you need to manually convert some sort of escape syntax back to newlines in an entrypoint wrapper script; the `.env` file can't itself contain embedded newlines.

Answer (score -1):

you can create shell variable from whole text and pass that variable to docker command

```
CERT="---start---
...
---end---"

docker run -e CERTIFICATE="$CERT"
```